# weird number appears on output-C

Tags: c, list, data-structures

I have made a simple list like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
 struct node{
    int am;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;
int main(){
int n;
    node *head=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *cur=head;
    printf("Give me a number:\n");
    scanf(" %d",head->am);
    cur=head;
    while(1){
        printf("Give me a number\n");
        scanf(" %d",&n);
        if(n==0)
            break;
        cur->am=n;
        cur->next=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        cur=cur->next;
        cur->next=null;
    }
    travel(head);
    printf("Total nodes available :%d\n",count(head));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now travel is supposed to go through each node in the list and display the integer saved in each node.

```
void travel(node *h){
    if(h==NULL)
        return;
    printf("Received data from node: \t %d\n",h->am);
    travel(h->next);
}
```

Now the problem is that when travel is called it wont print the integer from the first node.It will also print another "Received data from node:" followed by a strange number.
For example
If i give 1,2,3,4 as inputs these are the results

```
Received data from node:         2
Received data from node:         3
Received data from node:         4
Received data from node:         4026432
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not directly related, but traversing the list recursively is a terrible idea.

Comment: `scanf(" %d",head->am);` make it `scanf("%d",&head->am);`

Comment: Enable compiler warnings or get a better compiler.

Comment: Put cur->am=n; before break.

Comment: The thing is that in the last time you're in the loop, when you break the loop the value `am` of the last node is not initialized thus it is a random number.

Comment: why no? can you be precise.... `head->am` is not address of the variable.

Comment: The first assign set first readed number to `head`, the second assign (the first assign in a loop) assign the number also to `head`, because in the first loop cur = head;

Comment: You have twice the same code in your program : `printf("Give me a number:\n"); scanf(" %d",head->am);`. This is bad design and it is actually the root of your problem. Take a piece of paper and a pencil and draw your list and come up with an entire new solution.

Comment: `cur->next=null;` ==>> `null, really?

Comment: unless your working with a 'bare hardware board' (no OS), the return type from the function: `main()` is always `int`.  Your compiler should have warned you about that.  Note: MS Visual Studio is rather flakey and will allow code that is missing (or has the wrong type) type returned from `main()`

Comment: when you are asking a question about a runtime problem, always post code that cleanly compiles, is 'relatively' short, and still shows the problem.  The posted code does not compile.  One reason is the missing `#include` statements.  Do you expect us to guess as to which header files you included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now the problem is that when travel is called it wont print the
>   integer from the first node

This can be precisely known from this part of the `main()` function

```
printf("Give me a number:\n");
scanf(" %d",head->am); //this is wrong use of scanf("%d",&head->am);
cur=head;
while(1){
    printf("Give me a number\n");
    scanf(" %d",&n);
    if(n==0)
        break;
    cur->am=n;
```

as I've mentioned you're **scanning wrongly** but that doesn't matter because later in the code in `while` loop you replace it this way...

- you scan number and store it at `head->am`
- then you assign `head` to `cur` so `head->am` and `cur->am` are both the same now... so in while loop when you first assign `n` to `cur->am`, it gets assigned to `head->am`. so this explains why you never get to print first node.

---

**Solution:**

- to overcome it ... in while loop, before assigning `cur->am=n` try doing:

  ```
  cur->next=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  cur=cur->next;
  //then... assign
  curr->am=n;
  ```

this way you'll not lose first node.

---

**suggestion:**

As someone has already said it's much easier to traverse/ travel the list using loops (never mind... if you want to do it recursively)

here's how you do it with the loops:

```
 void travel(node *h)
 {
    if(h==NULL)
        return; //list is empty,consider printing "list empty" :)
    while(h!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Received data from node: \t %d\n",h->am);
        h=h->next;
    }
}
```

---

To put all together your code without changing the `travel()` function as suggested would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int am;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;

void travel(node *h);

int main() //I have a habit of returning values from main() :)
{
    int n;
    node *head=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *cur=head;
    printf("Give me a number:\n");
    scanf(" %d",&head->am);
    cur=head;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Give me a number\n");
        scanf(" %d",&n);
        if(n==0)
            break;
        cur->next=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        cur=cur->next;
        cur->am=n;                     //NOTE:here's the change!
        cur->next=NULL;
    }
    travel(head);
    return 0; //just to signify successful compilation
}

void travel(node *h)
{
    if(h==NULL)
        return;
    printf("Received data from node: \t %d\n",h->am);
    travel(h->next);
}
```

**Sample Input :** `5 6 3 1 0`

**Sample Output :**

```
Give me a number:
5
Give me a number
6
Give me a number
3
Give me a number
1
Give me a number
0
Received data from node:     5
Received data from node:     6
Received data from node:     3
Received data from node:     1
```

Comment: @cssGEEK are you only allowed to use travel recursively?

Comment: Fine... @cssGEEK Hope the above code helpful in solving your problem :)

Comment: i also return values from main but it was the example i wrote here that i did not do it :)

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) those issues:

1. The line `scanf(" %d",head->am)` is wrong since `scanf()` expects an address of the memory location of the expected value meaning `&head->am`.
2. Your loop scans a number and puts it in the current node and only after it creates a new node. Therefore, the first number you enter will be overridden (after fixing the first issue) and the last node created will contain random data because the loop will terminate after entering `0` but *before* putting anything in the last node.

Answer (score 1):

I propose like this:

```
int main(void){
    int n;
    node anchor = {0, NULL};//dummy head
    node *head, *cur = &anchor;

    while(1){
        printf("Give me a number\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n==0)
            break;
        cur->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
        cur = cur->next;
        cur->am = n;
        cur->next = NULL;
    }
    head = anchor.next;

    travel(head);
    printf("Total nodes available :%d\n", count(head));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Return value from `malloc()` must be checked.

Comment: @s7amuser this is a toy program, so error checks are not really needed, but the answer should include "error checking omitted for simplicity".

Comment: @MichaelWalz Sure but since this program is extremely small and simple in any case, adding proper error checking and (as pointed out by the author) memory handing by an experienced programmer will benefit the OP and the community.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing & at the first scanf:

```
scanf(" %d", &head->am);
```

But it could be made to do all the scanf inside the while:

```
int main(){
    node *head=0;
    node *cur=0;
    node *prev=0;
    while(1){
        prev = cur;
        cur=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        cur->next=NULL;
        printf("Give me a number\n");
        scanf("%d",&cur->am);
        if(cur->am==0)
            break;
        if(head == NULL) head = cur;
        if(prev != NULL) prev->next = cur; 
    }
    travel(head);
    printf("Total nodes available :%d\n",count(head));
    return 0;
}
```

I hope I didnt make any mistake as I wrote it in this SO editor..

and as someone said, you should free the linked list .. but thats out of scope here..

HTH

Comment: Your code will segfault immediately since you will be reading the first number into `&cur->am` when `cur` is `NULL`. Also, you must check the return address from `malloc` to make sure it is not `NULL`.

Comment: Doesn't work. Minus one unless you correct. Also `node *head=0;` should be `node *head=null;` or better `node *head=NULL;`

Comment: @MichaelWalz ok ok .. I am not a compiler :D

Comment: @otopolsky if you're not a compiler you should compile and run your answers before posting them

Comment: @MichaelWalz .. I expected this, compiled.. its working.. I should have written pseudo code

Comment: Better, but still crashing here. The `next` pointer of the last node is not initialized.

Comment: @MichaelWalz hm, fixed - should be less lazy next time, thanks for help